# Must the Purim feast take place in a location where it's Purim?

Tags: halacha, purim, eating, location, shushan-purim

Somebody who is obligated to keep Shushan-Purim (on 15th Adar); must they eat the Seudat Purim in a location where Shushan Purim is being celebrated?

In other words, on Shushan Purim, can a Yerushalmi go eat his Purim Seuda in Netanya?

I can't think of a reason why not, since the Seuda is an obligation on the person, not on the location. Yet I cannot find anybody who specifically mentions it. (I've searched the Shulchan Aruch, Kitzur SA, Aruch HaShulchan, Kitzur Yalkut Yosef.)

However, somebody mentioned that maybe there's a lack of Simchat Purim if it's not Purim.

The same question & answer would apply to Mishloach Manot and Matanot L'Evyanim, I assume.

For Megilla reading it seems clear in Halacha ([סימן תרפח](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_39.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2):ה ) that you read in the location you are in:

> בֶּן עִיר שֶׁהָלַךְ לַכְּרַךְ, אוֹ בֶּן כְּרַךְ שֶׁהָלַךְ לָעִיר, אִם הָיָה דַּעְתּוֹ לַחֲזֹר לִמְקוֹמוֹ  בִּזְמַן קְרִיאָה (שֶׁל י''ד) וְנִתְעַכֵּב וְלֹא חָזַר, **קוֹרֵא בִּמְקוֹמוֹ**; וְאִם לֹא הָיָה בְּדַעְתּוֹ לַחֲזֹר אֶלָּא לְאַחַר זְמַן הַקְּרִיאָה, קוֹרֵא עִם אַנְשֵׁי הַמָּקוֹם שֶׁהוּא שָׁם‏

I'm looking for a source, either way, or else for a good reason why the Yerushalmi should have his feast in a *walled* city.

Comment: I would think the other halachos or Purim would be analogous to reading the megila.

Comment: Except that if you are stuck in the wrong location, you can lein megillah for yourself on the correct day (Rambam)

Comment: Are you asking about someone who _generally_ lives in Yerushalayim but goes out of town for the whole Purim, or someone who spends Purim in Yerushalayim and leaves Yerushalayim early afternoon of Adar 15?

Comment: @YeZ - the latter.

Answer (score 5):

During a shiur about Purim the rav (who is a musmach of Ner Yisrael and gives a chaburah there)  mentioned that **all** the halachos of Purim follow the halachos of listening to the megillah as far as the location difference. Thus, someone who is in the United States for Purim will have the seudah on the 14th, even if he is from Yerushalayim. Similarly if he is in Netanya, and not returning to Yerushalayim for the 15th, he will also eat the seudah on the 14th.

I just found the exact halachos of someone who is in one place or the other in פסקי תשובה edited by Rav Simcha Rabinowitz (my Rav provided the sefer and pointed to the correct area) starting at דף תקכט which goes through all the details and various circumstances.

דף תקלב סעיף ג contains tha halachos of someone who leaves Yerushalayim on the 15th. If he leaves after alos hashachar of the 15th (in which case he is chayav to say the megillah in Yerushalayim), but **has not yet read the megillah**, then he must read the megillah **with a bracha** even outside Yerushalayim.

**My Conclusion**
This is analogous to the case in which someone leaves Yerushalayim after hearing the megillah but before eating the seudah. He would therefore be chayav to eat the seudah, where-ever he happens to be.

There are cases given in which he would be "פטור מכאן ומכאן" (Not obligated in either place) and other cases in which he reads without a bracha. This would have the implications for the seudah.

I did not have a chance to consider if the aniyim must be in Yerushalayim (so that they can use the money for Purim) or not. Similarly for mishloach manos.

Comment: If you [edit] in the name of your _rav_, it would increase the value of this answer.

Comment: I don't think this answered the question.  I think we are asking about someone who spent the 14th and 15th in Yerushalayim, and then went to Netanya on the afternoon of the 15th.  I don't think there is any question that he is a ben Yerushalayim for his Purim obligations.

Comment: @YeZ OK I will double check on this part of the question.

Comment: @YeZ I asked my Rav and he leant me the sefer I required and showed me which area the the answer would probably be. The answer is from what I read and any misteaks [sic] are mine.